# Is it considered dual boot when I installed ubuntu in a separate hard drive?

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, bios

I can't seem to find an answer to my question so if someone knows a post that answers my question, I'd be grateful if you can send me there.

I have currently set up my laptop to have windows installed on a M.2 nvme and ubuntu on a separate internal HDD. When installing ubuntu, I took out the M.2 to make sure I didn't wipe the wrong hard drive. Is this still considered dual booting since I have to go and change the boot order or is it still dual booting? Another question is will this configuration allow me to keep window's fast start up and the bios's fast startup or do I have to turn window's fast start off? I tried booting up with secure boot on both drives and they work, albeit slowly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That is dualboot too. You have one computer with two OSs on it, you can boot one or the other = dualboot.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! So is it still harmful to keep window's fast startup then? I also read somewhere that ubuntu can work with the bios's fast start and secure boot, but I want to make sure that this is also true.

Comment: "to keep window's fast startup:"  That basically is a hibernation method where microsoft RELOADS the hibernation file.So any outside source (ie Linux mounting the windows disk) that changes files on disk will get deleted as soon as the reload occurs. That is a definition of data corruption. Linux fixed this by refusing to mount windows so if you can live without that feel free to use it.

Comment: "secure boot" That is (U)EFI. We hardly use anything else nowadays so yes that is fine. Just a bit of a different approach needed when you initially setup an empty disk

Comment: With Windows fast start up on, it sets hibernation flag. The grub will not boot it, but you can boot from BIOS/UEFI boot menu. And you cannot mount any NTFS partitions read/write. You may be able to manually mount read only.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks! so just to be clear, since I don't need windows mounted to linux and vice versa, it's totally fine to keep fast startup on windows then? That's cool linux doesn't mount the disk and that actually explains why I couldn't find the other drive.

Comment: @oldfred So with the hibernation flag, the wholedisk is set to read only? Thanks and sorry for asking a lot, this is pretty new to me.

Comment: All NTFS partitions will be hibernated. Windows does not really see Linux partitions.